# Jquery TypeError

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jqtouch, typeerror

In jquery - what does `(d||"").split` do?

I've got a jqtouch webapp which throws up the following error from the jquery file:

> TypeError: Result of expression '(d||"").split' [undefined] is not a function.

I've tried different versions of jquery but no joy. Is it something important or can I ignore it?

edit: This is the part of the function it comes from. I'm not really sure how much to include here but its line 68 from jquery.min:

```
if(c.isFunction(f)){e=f;f=w}for(d=(d||"").split(" ");
```

edit 2:
I think its got to be caused by this function here from photoswipe.js:

```
// Set up the options 
    Code.PhotoSwipe.Current.setOptions(opts);


    // Tell PhotoSwipe about the photos
    Code.PhotoSwipe.Current.setImages(thumbEls);


    if (useEventDelegation){

        /*
         * Use event delegation rather than setting a click event on each 
         * thumb element.
         */
        containerEl.addEventListener('click', function(e){

            if (e.target === e.currentTarget){
                return;
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            var findNode = function(clickedEl, targetNodeName, stopAtEl){

                if (Util.isNothing(clickedEl) || Util.isNothing(targetNodeName) || Util.isNothing(stopAtEl)){
                    return null;
                }

                if (clickedEl.nodeName === targetNodeName){
                    return clickedEl;
                }

                if (clickedEl === stopAtEl){
                    return null;
                }

                return findNode(clickedEl.parentNode, targetNodeName, stopAtEl);
            };


            var clickedEl = findNode(e.target, thumbEls[0].nodeName, e.currentTarget);

            if (Util.isNothing(clickedEl)){
                return;
            }

            showPhotoSwipe(clickedEl);

        }, false);

    }
    else{

        // Add a click event handler on each element
        for (var i = 0; i < thumbEls.length; i++){

            var thumbEl = thumbEls[i];
            thumbEl.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);

        }

    }

    return thumbEls;

};
swipew
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I've tried 1.6.1, 1.5.1 and 1.4.2 amongst others and they all throw up the same error.

Comment: the problem is most likely in your code instead of trying to figure out why they are doing in jqtouch I suggest you ask whats wrong with your code. at least show us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what is wrong

Comment: check out my answer. the problem is not with jquery.

Comment: i didn't think it would be - but I hoped it might help to locate where the problem is.

Comment: please provide the complete source of the HTML and JS you use, (instead of the jqtouch source). Than i can help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code out:

```
var d = "matter";
(d||"").split("a"); //array: ["m","tter"]

var a = false;
(a||"").split("a"); //empty string

var c = true;
(c||"").split("a"); //type error
```

the || expression is a boolean check. If the left value is true (casted to boolean) then always return with the left, but if false then returns with the right.

```
"left"|| false  == "left"
"left"||"right" == "left"
 false||"right" == "right"
```

if `d` is **[boolean false](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_boolean.asp)** it will return with the `""` value, and then no error, but if the `d` is boolean true *(boolean true is everything which is not boolean false)* but not a string it can be a `TypeError`. Make sure that the `d` is converted to string with `.toString()`

`true.split("r")` will be type error, so you should use `true.toString().split("r")` and it will give you `["t","ue"]`

So in the **common** form **`(d||"").toString().split("r")` will be never type error**

---

### update

Oh i see your problem. I could help you better if you provide some source. Btw make sure you pass the right argument type to the invoked function. I dont know which fnction are you using but I am sure you pass something boolean or a number instead of a string, and i guess the problem is aboute .css() isn't it?
http://api.jquery.com/ documentation of jquery

Comment: if `d` is **thruthy** .. eg: a non-zero number, an array, an object, a regex, etc... not *just* `true`

Comment: Thanks - a lot of this is way of my head (i'm a mere html/css worker) but could it must be to do with an image gallery plug in thats trying to call a large image.. I'm also seeing this in Safari devloper:
TypeError: Result of expression 'thumbEls[0]' [undefined] is not an object.
jqtouch.js:98633: Called clickHandler
jqtouch.js:964: Need to prevent default click behavior
jqtouch.js:960: Converting click event to a tap event
jqtouch.js:980: Called tapHandler
jqtouch.js:635Animation could not be found. Using slideleft.
jqtouch.js:985: Called showPageByHref
jqtouch.js:98101: Called insertPages

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to split a string into an array based on a regular expression.

It should probably be something like:  split(d||"");

Why don't you edit your post to include the surrounding code?

Comment: The surronding code is embededed in jquery min file (line 68) - I've just got no idea what might be causing it but I've added the code above..

Comment: Could you try a non-minimized version of jQuery and then post the code where the error occurred?